# Oculus quest screen sharing with Agora

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io, oculus

I am using Agora.io in Unity to perform screen sharing and it works well when there are two desktop PCs involved. Now I am trying to achieve the same with Oculus Quest and one PC. The PC will have a raw image texture that shows Oculus screen view. Unfortunately there is no input at all, there is only a black screen. But remind you it works well when two PCs or even an android phone is connected, it displays the screen view. It only does not work when Oculus Quest is connected. I have even given all permissions required for Oculus to achieve this but it does not work.

EDIT: I am aware that I must change Screen.width and Screen.height to a custom render texture and attach this to a camera. I also did that but this time the output was null even in the Desktop mode.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using agora_gaming_rtc;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ScreenShare : MonoBehaviour {
    Texture2D mTexture;
    Rect mRect;
    [SerializeField]
    private string appId = "Your_AppID";
    [SerializeField]
    private string channelName = "agora";
    public IRtcEngine mRtcEngine;
    int i = 100;
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("ScreenShare Activated");
        mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.getEngine (appId);
        // enable log
        mRtcEngine.SetLogFilter (LOG_FILTER.DEBUG | LOG_FILTER.INFO | LOG_FILTER.WARNING | LOG_FILTER.ERROR | LOG_FILTER.CRITICAL);
        // set callbacks (optional)
        mRtcEngine.SetParameters ("{\"rtc.log_filter\": 65535}");
        //Configure the external video source
        mRtcEngine.SetExternalVideoSource (true, false);
        // Start video mode
        mRtcEngine.EnableVideo ();
        // allow camera output callback
        mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver ();
        // join channel
        mRtcEngine.JoinChannel (channelName, null, 0);
        //Create a rectangle width and height of the screen
        mRect = new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        //Create a texture the size of the rectangle you just created
        mTexture = new Texture2D ((int) mRect.width, (int) mRect.height, TextureFormat.BGRA32, false);
    }
    void Update () {
        //Start the screenshare Coroutine
        StartCoroutine (shareScreen ());
    }
    //Screen Share
    IEnumerator shareScreen () {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
        //Read the Pixels inside the Rectangle
        mTexture.ReadPixels (mRect, 0, 0);
        //Apply the Pixels read from the rectangle to the texture
        mTexture.Apply ();
        // Get the Raw Texture data from the the from the texture and apply it to an array of bytes
        byte[] bytes = mTexture.GetRawTextureData ();
        // Make enough space for the bytes array
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf (bytes[0]) * bytes.Length;
        // Check to see if there is an engine instance already created
        IRtcEngine rtc = IRtcEngine.QueryEngine ();
        //if the engine is present
        if (rtc != null) {
            //Create a new external video frame
            ExternalVideoFrame externalVideoFrame = new ExternalVideoFrame ();
            //Set the buffer type of the video frame
            externalVideoFrame.type = ExternalVideoFrame.VIDEO_BUFFER_TYPE.VIDEO_BUFFER_RAW_DATA;
            // Set the video pixel format
            externalVideoFrame.format = ExternalVideoFrame.VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT.VIDEO_PIXEL_BGRA;
            //apply raw data you are pulling from the rectangle you created earlier to the video frame
            externalVideoFrame.buffer = bytes;
            //Set the width of the video frame (in pixels)
            externalVideoFrame.stride = (int) mRect.width;
            //Set the height of the video frame
            externalVideoFrame.height = (int) mRect.height;
            //Remove pixels from the sides of the frame
            externalVideoFrame.cropLeft = 10;
            externalVideoFrame.cropTop = 10;
            externalVideoFrame.cropRight = 10;
            externalVideoFrame.cropBottom = 10;
            //Rotate the video frame (0, 90, 180, or 270)
            externalVideoFrame.rotation = 180;
            // increment i with the video timestamp
            externalVideoFrame.timestamp = i++;
            //Push the external video frame with the frame we just created
            int a = rtc.PushVideoFrame (externalVideoFrame);
            Debug.Log (" pushVideoFrame =       " + a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you manage that render texture? Does it link to a camera?  You should assign the render texture to a camera and grab the data off it.  [Here is an example from a different project](https://gist.github.com/icywind/329b42b9525a5fd3b1579bb2731f86bf#file-agoravideochat_pushvideo-cs) that you may take a look at how render texture data is being used.

Also note that you are following a dated tutorial where the API changed slightly after the SDK updates. The example is also dated on that regard.
The Pixel format should use RGBA instead of BGRA for cross platform compatibility.

```
externalVideoFrame.format = ExternalVideoFrame.VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT.VIDEO_PIXEL_RGBA;
```

Comment: Hello I tried that but with no luck was I able to achieve it. Can I create a custom render texture and then take in input from my camera?

Comment: Yes, like you said, you should create a custom render texture and set it to the camera, and reading the raw data off that render texture.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to OpenGLES3 from Vulkan.

I guess ReadPixels() function is not working in Quest 2 with Vulkan API